# visual studio 2019 табуляция

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

После добавление в c# проект Angular 7, IDE начала вместо 4 пробелов ставить 2... В чем может быть проблема

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В проекте у вас должен быть файл `*.editorconfig`. В нем есть настроечка `intent_size`. Ей нужно присвоить значение 4 для нужных форматов файлов. Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
[*.cs]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```